# Determine if child elements available for message

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So inside my JavaScript, I have the following snippet:

```
const map = $window.find('#map-office-' + $sender.data('office_id'));
```

Which gives me an output:
[image]

Now inside the first element, there is a `children` attribute, which shows the following:

When the `<script>` tag is disabled, it shows no children.
[image]

When the `<script>` tag is enabled, it shows children.
[image]

How can I make it where it would act like this:

If map doesn't have children, inject a innerHTML message, otherwise render showMap function.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: `if (map[0].children.length > 0) { // do something } else { // do something else }`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, what's the right approach to build out a innerHTML but have it structured into `<div>` and etc.. DOM Table?

Comment: `map.html('<div>...</div>')`